# What is the meaning of 0x61C88647 constant in ThreadLocal.java

Tags: java, optimization, constants

I recently read an article about [Equation Group's Sophisticated Hacking](http://arstechnica.co.uk/security/2016/08/code-dumped-online-came-from-omnipotent-nsa-tied-hacking-group/) and the smoking gun is a constant which also appears in JDK 8 source code e.g. [ThreadLocal.java](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/tip/src/share/classes/java/lang/ThreadLocal.java)

What is the meaning of HASH_INCREMENT constant and how does it improve performance?

```
/**
 * The difference between successively generated hash codes - turns
 * implicit sequential thread-local IDs into near-optimally spread
 * multiplicative hash values for power-of-two-sized tables.
 */
private static final int HASH_INCREMENT = 0x61c88647;
```

Comment: Your question is answered in the comment included in your question.

Comment: @Kayaman As you can see in the answer, there's more behind it.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

TLDR: It's an example of [Fibonacci hashing](https://web.archive.org/web/20161121124236/http://brpreiss.com/books/opus4/html/page214.html).

If you convert 0x61c88647 into decimal, you'll get 1640531527 which is nonsensical until you realise that in 32 bits, it's the signed version of 2654435769. Again this number seems a bit odd until you realise that it is  2<sup>32</sup> ÷ φ where φ is the golden ratio (√5+1)÷2.

Now how does this fit into ThreadLocal? When you create a new ThreadLocal it is assigned an ID based on the previous id + our magic number. It's put into a ThreadLocalMap. In the event of a clash, the ThreadLocalMap puts the value into the next available space. Our magic value allows an optimal "spreading out" of the values in this hash in order to avoid this.

Comment: That "until you realise" made me weep. Thanks.

Comment: The mathematics of hashing algorithms will do that to someone.

Answer (score 1):

0x61c88647 = 1640531527 ≈ 2 ^ 32 * (1 - 1 / φ), φ = (√5 + 1) ÷ 2, it is an another Golden ratio Num of 32 bits.